# Need help for Contacts query to incoorporate to a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I'm trying to create an apex class and visualforce page to create a query that pulls all contacts that the Picklistfield__c contains "associate". we also want to add a sub query that will pull another contact record's name where the lookupfield__c is referenced to the Id of the current contact in the query. the idea is below:

```
SELECT Name, Email, Phone, 
    (SELECT Name FROM Contacts Where lookupfield__c = *currentContactId* )
FROM Contact
WHERE Picklistfield__c LIKE '%Associate%'
```

But

Is it possible to pull the ID of the current contact record in the query and use it in as filter for the sub-query.

I do apologize for in advance if I named them incorrectly as I'm not a certified developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty simple to achieve.
In Salesforce Setup if you open the Custom LookupField "lookupfield__c" in Object Manager you will see the "Child Relationship Name". That's the name you provided when creating the lookup.
Given this child relationship name is "CustomContacts"
you can simply query:

`SELECT Name, Email, Phone, (SELECT Name FROM CustomContacts__r) FROM Contact WHERE Picklistfield__c LIKE '%Associate%'`

Note: When you iterate over the Contacts in APEX you need to have a nested for Loop.

```java
for(Contact con : associateContacts){
    //do something with main contact;

    for(Contact child : con.CustomContacts){
        //process child records;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close to correct. For custom relationships, you'll need to add `__r` to the end of the child relationship name in the subquery. I like to think of it as the `__c` stands for "custom" and the `__r` stands for "relationship".

Comment: Also, while I think it's a good idea/safe to always use a nested loop to access child records, it's not always required. If you have less than ~200 child records per parent, then you can access the embedded `List<SObject>` directly.

Comment: Thanks @Derek F. I was able to create the query with your guidance. I'm a solo admin so this type of approach will help me in the future. Cheers!